# Laravel 4 inherited attributes are null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model, which inherits from the Toddish\Verify Laravel package (https://github.com/Toddish/Verify-L4/blob/master/src/Toddish/Verify/Models/User.php)

All I want to do is add some attributes:

```
use Toddish\Verify\Models\User as VerifyUser;

class User extends VerifyUser
{
    public function __construct (array $attributes = array()) {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->fillable = array_merge ($this->fillable, array(
            'salutation', 'title', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'phonenumber', 'mobilenumber'
        ));
    }
}
```

When I run a test:

```
class UserTest extends TestCase {

    public function testUserCreation () {
        $user = User::create(
            [
                'username' => 'testusername',
                'email' => 'email@test.com',
                'password' => 'testpassword',
                'salutation' => 'MrTest',
                'title' => 'MScTest',
                'firstname' => 'Testfirstname',
                'lastname' => 'Testlastname',
                'phonenumber' => 'testPhoneNumber',
                'mobilenumber' => 'testMobileNumber',
            ]
        );

        $this->assertEquals($user->salutation, 'MrTest');
        $this->assertEquals($user->title, 'MScTest');
        $this->assertEquals($user->firstname, 'Testfirstname');
        $this->assertEquals($user->lastname, 'Testlastname');
        $this->assertEquals($user->phonenumber, 'testPhoneNumber');
        $this->assertEquals($user->mobilenumber, 'testMobileNumber');
    }
}
```

I get the following:

```
1) UserTest::testUserCreation
Failed asserting that 'MrTest' matches expected null.
```

All of the asserts return null. But I checked and the database columns exist. So why is that attribute null?

EDIT:

If I swap the assert parameters:

```
$this->assertEquals('MrTest', $this->salutation);
```

I get this:

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: UserTest::$salutation
```

Comment: As a side note, your assertion parameters are backwards, the expected result should come first. That will make your error messages make more sense ;)

Comment: Cool, thanks! Now the error is "ErrorException: Undefined property: UserTest::$salutation"

Comment: What is your assertion? It should be `$this->assertEquals('MrTest', $user->salutation);`

Comment: strange error, sounds like there's `$this->salutation` being called somewhere by that error?

Comment: It should be `$user->salutation` not `$this->salutation` in your assertion.

Comment: That is so weird. I changed it to $user and it worked. So I backed up in my editor to see if that was the original problem, and now the tests pass.

Comment: awesome, chasing the green :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to move the fillable override to be above the call to `parent::__construct($attributes);`

Making it:

```
public function __construct (array $attributes = array()) {
    $this->fillable = array_merge ($this->fillable, array(
        'salutation', 'title', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'phonenumber', 'mobilenumber'
    ));
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

This is because the main `Model` classes constructor uses the `fillable` array, so it needs to be set before the constructor is called.

**[EDIT]** Updated answer to include only the section that is required, and added some explanation of why it is the case

Comment: That does not change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes. I changed it to look like what you said.

Comment: Bizarre, the changing of the order or events in the constructor should fix this. Since the fillable array is used by the parent constructor, so it needs to be set first. What is the error you're currently getting with the constructor I have above?

Comment: Well I'm slightly confused as to what actually happened, but I think this is the answer so I have accepted it.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident it's the ordering of the items in the constructor.

Comment: Yeah I think I must have tested without saving first at some point.